# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on VPN

Tags: connection, vpn

I have a website that is not loading while on our VPN. The site just loads continually until it times out. However, if we disconnect from the VPN and reload the page, it works. I can even reconnect to the VPN after and it still allows me to continue.

```
Failed to load resource: 
net:: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

We tried disconnecting from the VPN, clearing the cache, hard reset, shutdown of the PC, Google Chrome updates, and trying multiple VPN locations. Happening for multiple users.